# Help to understand “Just screaming ‘F***’ as loud as i can into the void,”

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning

> “Just screaming ‘F***’ as loud as i can into the void,” added another.

I see this sentence in [this article](https://www.yahoo.com/news/democrats-risky-longshot-blocking-trumps-next-supreme-court-pick-214353853.html). It seems to me that the sentence is missing a verb in the clause "*i can into the void*". Is it an idiom or saying? I can probably get a rough idea about what it means, but I don't think I fully understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence is missing a subject and the helping/auxillary verb. This has caused confusion because you have mistaken "I can" for the subject and verb. You have broken the sentence up incorrectly. The sentence breaks up into *"[I am] Just screaming 'F'"*, *"as loud as I can"*, *"into the void"*.

The reader is left to assume that the subject is *"I"*. The verb in this sentence is *"am screaming"*.

*"into the void"* describes where the subject is directing their screaming. The subject is screaming at nothing in particular. They are screaming out into the universe.

*"as loud as I can"* is an adjective of *"screaming"*. The subject is screaming as loud as they are physically able to scream.

Variations of *"screaming into the void"* are used in English to describe a feeling of extreme frustration. Imagine that you are so frustrated that you want to scream. The writer may even mean it literally!